# Internet Connection cuts out

Tags: wireless, networking, 13.04

I have a wireless internet connection and whenever I use Steam it usually cuts off. Plus whenever I use Bit-torrent it generally cuts off too. I moved closer to my router but it still happens. I heard that there is some connectivity issues already in Ubuntu 13.04 but I never found an answer to resolve it. 
I heard you need this so here you go.

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8191SEvA Wireless LAN Controller [10ec:8171] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1467]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8192se
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 02)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1605]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

Help would be nice

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is check if your wi-fi card does need a (sort of) driver.
because ubuntu uses one driver for all kind of cards.
i had to do this on my asus n55sf laptop.
you have a rtl8191SEvA card from Realtek
the download [click here](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&ProdID=226&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true)

choose the second linux table because this one is for the rtl8191SEvA card.

**i do not know how to intall it or place it in the correct folder.**

maybe somebody else could help him with it